# Protractor getting stale element reference in page object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, protractor, iteration

I am verifying the filter options in a page. Every time I select an option I submit the filters then the page refreshes with the new result. Again I click on the filter button and need to select next radio button. But I am getting stale element reference error.

```
filterButton.click().then(function () {
  filteroptions.count().then(function (totalradios) {
    console.log("before start" + totalradios);
    filteroptions.each(function (radiooption, index) {
      radiooption.getText()  //getting error at this place on the second iteration
       .then(function (radioName) {
        console.log(radioName, index);
      })
      radiooption.click().then(() => {
        filterSubmit.click().then(function () {
          console.log(totalradios, ' ', index)
          if (index <= totalradios) {
            filterButton.click();
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Updated from each(function) to For loop

```
 var filteroptions = element.all(by.css("md-radio-group.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid._md.layout-row.ng-not-empty md-radio-button")); 

filterButton.click().then(function () {
  filteroptions.count().then(function (totalradios, async) {
   console.log("before start" + totalradios);
   for (var i = 0; i < totalradios; i++) {
   console.log("recalulated true " + totalradios);
   (function (index) {
    console.log("select filter option");
    filteroptions.get(index).click();
    console.log("click submit button");
    filterSubmit.click();
    console.log("click filter button");
    filterButton.click();
    console.log("get new totalcounts");
    let setradios = filteroptions.count().then((value) => {
    return value;
   })
   console.log("recalulated totalradios" + setradios);
   totalradios = setradios;
   })(i);
  }
  })
})
```

Tried to read the list in a separate function

```
var getfiltercount = function () {
  filteroptions = element.all(by.css("md-radio-group.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid._md.layout-row.ng-not-empty md-radio-button")); // filtertext
  return filteroptions.count().then(function (addradios) {
  console.log("addradios is " + addradios);
 })
  return addradios;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because selenium will also treat below situation as entering new page:

- Page whole refresh, even the page url not change
- Page partial refresh, even the page url not change

Once selenium detect entering new page, the reference of elements found on previous page are invalid, if you still use them in script, selenium will report
StaleReferenceException.

To resolve this problem is simple to find the element again on new page to get the new reference for later using.

// function to test when choose `yes` radio button

```
function testYesRaidoButton() {
    // click `yes` radio button
    element(<locator of `yes` raido button>).click();
    // find how many new radio buttons will appear after choose `yes`
    element.all(<locator of sub radio buttons of `yes`>).count()

    .then(function (totalradios) {
        console.log("before start " + totalradios);

        for(var i=0;i<totalradios;i++) {

            (function(index) {

                // click one of new radio button of `yes`
                element.all(<locator of sub radio buttons of `yes`>).get(index).click();

                // click `submit` button
                element(<locator of filterSubmit>).click();

                // click `yes` radio button on `new page` again
                element(<locator of `yes` raido button>).click();

            })(i);

        }
    });
}
```

// function to test when choose `no` radio button

```
function testNoRadioButton() {
    // click `no` radio button
    element(<locator of `no` raido button>).click();
    // find how many new radio buttons will appear after choose `no`
    element.all(<locator of sub radio buttons of `yes`>).count()

    .then(function (totalradios) {
        console.log("before start " + totalradios);

        for(var i=0;i<totalradios;i++) {

            (function(index) {

                // click one of new radio button of `no`
                element.all(<locator of sub radio buttons of `no`>).get(index).click();

                // click `submit` button
                element(<locator of filterSubmit>).click();

                // click `no` radio button on `new page` again
                element(<locator of `no` raido button>).click();

            })(i);

        }
    }); 
}
```

Actually, the two function has many similar code lines, 
you can optimize and merge into one function to accept different parameter value to archive same purpose.

Alternative solution to archive some goal by using two loop, but not recommend to do as that, because code is hard to read and understand, pretty not friendly.

```
// iterate `yes` and 'no'
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

  (function(__index) {

    element.all(<locator of `yes` and `no` radio button>).get(__index).click();

    element.all(<locator of new radio buttons>).count()

    .then(function(totalradios) {
      console.log("before start " + totalradios);

      // iterate new radio buttons
      for (var i = 0; i < totalradios; i++) {

        (function(index) {

          // click one of new radio buttons
          element.all(<locator of new radio buttons>).get(index).click();

          // click `submit` button
          element(<locator of filterSubmit> ).click();

          // click `yes` or `no` radio button on `new page` again
          element.all(<locator of `yes` and `no` radio button>).get(__index).click();

        })(i);

      }
    });

  })(j)

}
```

Comment: Actually I tried similar way but got other issue. Based on the radio option selected it enables other radios. So let say I have 5 radio buttons and selecting one enables two more radio options. The condition in forloop (totalradios) will still take initial 5 and not the updated one 7. can I update the value `filterButton.click().then(function () {
filteroptions.count().then(function (totalradios) {
for (var i = 0; i<totalradios; i++) {
filteroptions.get(i).click();
filterSubmit.click();
filterButton.click();
filteroptions.count().then(totalradios =>{
return totalradios;
})
}`

Comment: I have  tow questions,  let say we have 5 radio buttons, after I clicked the 5 radio buttons,  12 new radio buttons increased on page,  then whenI click those 12 new radio buttons, they will trigger more new radio buttons display on page or not?   Clicking radio buttons will only increase new radio button, will not decrease radio button?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I already had similar code as I copied in my previous comment. regarding your question. I have yes no radio buttons along with someother radios (3 more), When I select Yes then it adds 4 more radios. my script collects the counts as 5 at the before for loop. When yes is selected it should again read the new list and update the totalradios in for loop so that it will run for 9 times instead of 5. please check my updated code

Comment: I'm not sure my understanding is correct. why you don't test `yes` and its sub radio buttons in one function, and test 'no' and its sub radio buttons in another function.   Testing all of them in one function increase the complex.

Comment: I have that in my mind to write two separate functions but just want to see if I can do it without splitting them.

Comment: Yes, you can do that by using two loop. The outer loop to iterate `yes` and `no` radio buttons, the inner loop to iterate new radio buttons.   I think it's no way to do that with only one loop.